# Finding $P(X > 1, Y \leq \frac{3}{2})$ given a joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given random variables $X$ and $Y$, and the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y}{4}I(0 < x < y < 2)$,

find $P(X > 1, Y \leq \frac{3}{2})$.

I first started by graphing the region that is given and concluded that:
$P(X > 1, Y \leq \frac{3}{2}) = \int_{1}^{2}\int_{x}^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{x^2+y}{4}dydx$. However, when I integrate this expression, I get a negative result, which contradicts that $0 \leq P(X > 1, Y \leq \frac{3}{2}) \leq 1$. What do I seem to be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound of $x$ should be $\frac{3}{2}$. Rest is correct.

If $y \lt \frac{3}{2}$, we cannot have $x \gt \frac{3}{2}$ as the density function is defined in the region $ \ 0 \lt x \lt y \lt 2$.

See the diagram. You need to integrate over the region shaded in orange.

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks! So, just to confirm, the correct expression would therefore be $\int_{1}^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_{x}^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{x^2+y}{4}dydx$?

Comment: @user62487108 yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\lt y$ and $y\le \frac{3}{2}$, then $x\le \frac{3}{2}$ so upper limit of $x$ integral is$\frac{3}{2}$ not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of integration is always determined by the intersection of the *event* and the *support* for the jpdf.

So it is $1<x, y\leqslant 3/2,\text{ and }0<x<y<2$ .

Which is to say: $1<x<y\leqslant 3/2$

---

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>1, Y\leq 3/2) &= \iint_{1<x~,~y\leqslant3/2}f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d \langle x,y\rangle\\[1ex]&=\iint_{1<x~,~y\leqslant 3/2~,~0<x<y<2}\dfrac{x^2+y}{4}\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle\\[1ex]&=\iint_{1<x< y\leqslant 3/2}\dfrac{x^2+y}{4}\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle\\[1ex]&=\int_1^{3/2}\int_x^{3/2}\dfrac{x^2+y}{4}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d x&=\int_1^{3/2}\int_1^y\dfrac{x^2+y}{4}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d  y\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$